# Logitech MX Anywhere 2 mouse won't stay connected

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, devices, logitech

If my MX Anywhere 2 bluetooth mouse isn't moved for around 5-15 seconds, it will disconnect and take 5-15 seconds to reconnect after it is physically moved. Sometimes after it reconnects an "Unknown" bluetooth device is appears to the list, and if I use my PC for a while this list of "Unknown" devices can grow quite large. But when I first boot up, there are no "Unknown" bluetooth devices.

[image: bluetooth devices]

I have had a problem with the mouse only on Ubuntu. No other bluetooth devices have the issue. Connecting the mouse on Windows seems to have no issues.

When I run `bt-device -i` I notice there are errors, but I cannot say it is related to the issue:

```
=>bt-device -i F4:EA:7E:8D:0B:E6
[F4:EA:7E:8D:0B:E6]
  Name: MX Anywhere 2
  Alias: MX Anywhere 2 [rw]
  Address: F4:EA:7E:8D:0B:E6
  Icon: input-mouse
  Class: 0x0

(bt-device:11651): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 19:15:42.553: g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
  Paired: 0

(bt-device:11651): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 19:15:42.554: g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
  Trusted: 0 [rw]

(bt-device:11651): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 19:15:42.554: g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
  Blocked: 0 [rw]

(bt-device:11651): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 19:15:42.554: g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
  Connected: 0
  UUIDs: [
(bt-device:11651): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 19:15:42.554: g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can't find a solution to this issue, and am hoping someone might know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the Logitech problem, but the solution in my case to the bt-device -i assertion errors was to use blueman-applet to disconnect, untrust, and then finally remove the device. Using bt-device to remove did not work.

I then re-paired the device and bt-device -i was happy again.